# Playwright not loading all thumbnails on page

Tags: python, scrapy, css-selectors, playwright-python

I'm using playwright with python.
I have a pages with multiple thumbnails (>10), but everytime playwright is not detecting more than 8 with the css selector. Even though I manually checked and there are all the selectors available.
Sample page :
https://www.ah.nl/bonus/groep/-13928?week=37
Sample code:

```
        await page.wait_for_load_state()
        grid_count = await page.locator('article.product-card-portrait_root__ZiRpZ').count()
        products = page.locator('article.product-card-portrait_root__ZiRpZ')
        try:
            await expect(products.nth(grid_count)).to_be_visible()
        except:
            ipdb.set_trace()
```

Every single time the page has more than 8 elements, it's going in the ipdb on the except.
How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is some kind of lazy load, at first, first 8 elements are loaded, if you scroll down, more content will load

Comment: Unfortunately there is no straight option to scroll in playwright, but there are some options as press key down and/or in JS there is a native way to scroll